# Runtime query does not work.Why?

Tags: ms-access

I have a Problem with my codes and it made me confuse.this is my scenario:

in my access Project I have a Form and subform that work together.I wanted to enhace my performance . I deceided to load my form and subforms in Runtime(from this [article](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performanceforms.htm)) .I put my query  on my form code, in  Form_load event like this:

```
Private Sub Form_load()
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT DISTINCTROW tb_bauteile.* " & _
   "FROM tb_bauteile LEFT JOIN FehlerCodes_akt_Liste ON tb_bauteile.CDT = FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.CDT " & _
   "WHERE (((FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Steuergerät)='MEDC17'))" & _
   "ORDER BY FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad;"
End Sub
```

but  another problem occured with another controls in my form.when i click another control .this function should be run:

```
Private Sub subPfadFilter(Kombifeld As Variant, Obd As String)
    Dim strKrit, strAuswahl, strSg As String

     If (IsNull(Me.CDT) Or (Me.CDT = "")) Then
            strAuswahl = "*"
        Else
            strAuswahl = Me.CDT
            blnFiltOn = True
        End If
    .....
```

but it doesn't work and say me **method or dataobjectt not found**( without this if statement works the function works fine .the problem come from CDT ) if I put the query  in Datasource in my form property that works properly

I cant understand the relation between these two things(putting the query on datasource of form property then working the if statement (CDT) good but when i put the query in Form load that does not work ) ,would you please help me if posible?have you any idee? 
thank you so much for your helps

Comment: I think there should be a space before ORDER BY. Don't know if that will make a difference....

Answer (score 3):

When using the "Me" reference, you need to ensure the code is behind the present form, you've mentioned that the Form_Load code is on there, but is the "subPfadFilter" somewhere else?

If so then it needs to either be moved on to this form, or change your reference to the forms name instead of "Me".

If it is on the form then the error seems to be complaining about the CDT item, you will need to confirm that this is the name of either a text field or a control on this form.

If it is then you can try inserting:

```
Me.Requery
```

After your SQL statement, this may wake up the forms reference to the object.

This bit is not essential but to avoid carrying out two tests on CDT and streamlining your code slightly I would amend to this:

```
If Me.CDT & "" = "" Then
    strAuswahl = "*"
Else
    strAuswahl = Me.CDT
    blnFiltOn = True
End If
```

This captures both Is Null or "" in one shot.

UPDATE:

For an unbound form, you need to set your form's controls via VB as well as the forms recordsource e.g:

```
Private Sub Form_load()

Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCTROW b.* " & _
                                 "FROM tb_bauteile As b LEFT JOIN FehlerCodes_akt_Liste As f " & _
                                 "ON b.CDT = f.CDT " & _
                                 "WHERE f.Steuergerät = 'MEDC17' " & _
                                 "ORDER BY f.Fehlerpfad;")

    rs.MoveFirst

    Me.CDT = rs!CDT

    'Any other fields go here

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

However if you are returning more than one record at a time then you will either need to stick with a bound form or perhaps use a listbox to display your information.  Unbound forms do not use the Forms "Recordset" property.

Note: I have also 'Aliased' the table names in your SQL statement, this is a good practice to get into : )

Comment: hey matt,thank you ...both of them (form_load and subPfadFilter) are on the same form and CDT is the name of a field on my DB but why does my code work when I put that code on datasource) it is not logicly

Comment: @iav-babak When you have the SQL in the datasource, then the form is opened with the controls already bound, when you set the SQL yourself (more the practice of un-bound forms) the controls may not always bind until you refresh (requery) the form. Are you hoping to use a bound or un-bound form in this case?

Comment: as I understanded my form was bounded (because SQL was in Datasource) and when I put the SQL in my Form code I changed it to the unbounded Form...when I put the SQL in my Form code it is 1-2 second faster  .I want to have this method ( unbound) and solve this problem too.

Comment: hey Matt,sorry I could not test your answer in the last days .the idea is nice but I have the problem again in this line:`Me.CDT = rs!CDT
`

Comment: @iav-babak In your second sub routine where the error occurs, I suggest using a form reference rather than "Me" e.g. "Forms!formname!ControlName"

Comment: thank you Matt,I changed it to `ufrm_bauteile.CDT=rs!CDT` but that does not work

Comment: @iav-babak It will be more like "Forms!ufrm_bauteile!CDT" The word forms is a part of the command and you need to use the ! sign throughout rathan than a .